# how is the azure internal server name mapped?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I was reviewing some Loggly logs that had been hooked up for Azure logging and I saw a reference to the following url:

```
https://rd000d3a305ece/MyCorp.WebService/DashboardProxy.svc/dashboards/monitordata
```

I'm assuming that rd000d3a305ece is some type of server name or some other type of pointer. How is this mapped and how can I navigate through the Azure portal to validate this reference?  It looks like the url reference above was output to the logs but the input was most likely a proper name like:

```
https://bizapp.mycorp/MyCorp.WebService/DashboardProxy.svc/dashboards/monitordata
```

Comment: well, given that it's rd + 6 hex(?) bytes, could very well be the MAC address of the VM.

Comment: RD was the code name of azure, Red Dog